# How to collect data from an unlimited number of items RadioButton?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{int i=0;}
@foreach (var e in Model.BlockList)
{ 
  @foreach (var e2 in e.RadioButtons)
  {
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("r"+i, e2.Id, false) @e2.ViewText</label><br />
  }
  i++;
}
```

Question: how in the controller through all the answers?

At this moment my Controller class look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DocAlpha a)
{
   List<int> results = new List<int>();
   int i = 0;

   while (Request.Params["r" + i.ToString()] != null)
   {
      int val = 0;

      if(int.TryParse(Request.Params.Get("r" + i.ToString()), out val))
      {
         results.Add(val);
      }
      i++;
   }

   return Index();
}
```

may be better ways?

Comment: Is this RadioButtons property an enum? If so, can it be made into a flagged enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an array of radio buttons names like so (note the names):

```
Html : 
<input type="text" name="r[0]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="r[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="r[2]" value="" />
<!--and so on -->
```

Then make your action accept an array:

```
public ActionResult TheAction (string[] r) {

}
```

The default model binder will automatically populate the answers array in your action with the values entered in the form.